# How to get @ViewChild()'s associated obj by the ViewChild name

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have a ViewChild declare for a form element:

```
@ViewChild('callerForm') callerFormObj: any;
```

actually I have multiple forms on this webpage all with their own ViewChild and associated object

My question is: if I have the form's name, can I get a reference somehow to ViewChild object: callerFormObj?

```
// Get control associated with property
let anElement = document.querySelector('[ng-reflect-name="' + propName + '"]'); // ng-reflect-name
// If control exists continue
if (anElement) {
  // Find controls associated form element
  let aForm = anElement.closest('form');
  if (aForm) {
    let formName = aForm.name; // e.g. for ViewChild above will be 'callerForm'
    // Get forms viewchild associated obj
    let formViewChildObj = ??????; // A reference to callerFormObj
  }
}
```

No jquery thanks!

Comment: `ViewChild` provide you with reference to components why do you need querySelector?

Comment: I wouldn't advice you to use `document.querySelector`. You probably need to change implementation of current functionality. Introduce new properties which will be in charge of determine whether control is exists. And take a look on `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: Hi Yuriy, I'm basically wanting manipulate the form objects dirty property, the only thing I have to start with is a property name, hence why I'm going through the dom to find what form it belongs to.

Comment: If you had reactive form you would easily make control dirty, and know which control is belongs to

Comment: Alright thanks, got some reading to do then